# como ubicar un popover, menuToggle y tituloHeader en ionic

Tags: ionic3

estoy haciendo un popover a mi aplicacion en ionic 3, y trabaja bien pero no se ve en una misma linea. me explico con la imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver el menuToggle, promociones y el Popover se ven  disparejos

mi codigo de donde esta el menu :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title text-left>{{params.title}}</ion-title>
    <button ion-button float-right icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)">
      <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
    </button> 
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

otro detallido es que el popover se ve con ese fondo negro. la idea es que se vea como el otro boton menutoggle... gracias. por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías encerrar cada botón en un grupo de botones algo así

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="danger">

    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title text-center>
      Page Title
    </ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)">
        <ion-icon name="options"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

te anexo un ejemplo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5hvkbq

Comment: correctisimo. ya le habia encontrado la solucion y es tal cual tu comentario gracias hermano..